# Why do I get the error: "NameError: global name 'pupiluserinputbox' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, nameerror

```
def pupiluserpass():
    global usernames, passwords
    usernameinp = pupiluserinputbox.get()
    passwordinp = pupilpasswordinputbox.get()
```

Why do I get the error: `NameError: global name 'pupiluserinputbox'` is not defined?

The input boxes are in another procedure:

```
def pupillogin():
   ruapupil = Label(app, text = "If you're a pupil log in here:")
   ruapupil.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

   pupilusername = Label(app, text = "Please enter your Username:")
   pupilusername.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
   pupiluserinputbox = Entry(app, width = 10)
   pupiluserinputbox.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

   pupilpassword = Label(app, text = "Please enter your Password:")
   pupilpassword.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
   pupilpasswordinputbox = Entry(app, width = 10)
   pupilpasswordinputbox.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

   pupilenter = Button(app, text = "Enter!", command = pupiluserpass)
   pupilenter.config(height = 1, width = 8)
   pupilenter.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

How can I make this work successfully and not get a `NameError`?

Comment: variables defined in one function are not visible in a separate function. Use `global` variables or put the functions in a class and assign the values as attributes to `self`.

Comment: +1 for the latter solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For a `class`, you should make the variables that carry those errors attributes to `self`, i.e. the current instance of that object. This is the de facto way to access these variables in other methods within the `class`. For example:

```
def pupiluserpass():
    ...
    usernameinp = self.pupiluserinbox.get()
    passwordinp = self.pupilpasswordinputbox.get()

def pupillogin():
    ...
    self.pupiluserinputbox = Entry(app, width = 10)
    self.pupiluserinputbox.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
    ...
    self.pupilpasswordinputbox = Entry(app, width = 10)
    self.pupilpasswordinputbox.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

You could also do lots of `global` declarations here instead but it is better to use `self`.

Comment: Using self I get this error:
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Is your code in `class` format? If not then it needs to be.